# iOS Strings Localization Get Base Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am looking to get the base value or english value for a localized string from a .string file. I am showing the user in the view controller the localized string but my function uses the base value or english value. I have searched everywhere but I cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. Maybe there is a much better way than using some string values.

Comment: For example I have a table view and every row has an localized string when the user clicks on one row I am sending the value of that string to another view controller, but I do not want to send the localized string I need the base string. I was thinking that maybe there is a quick solution to get the base value not the specific language translated string.

Comment: Why do you need the base string in the other ViewController?

Comment: I am doing some internet query with the value selected by the user but I cannot do it for every localized value I just need the base value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you show your localized string. If you are using something as below you can update code:

```
-(NSString *)languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString *) key showKey: (BOOL) show
{
    NSString *language = [[NSString alloc] init]
   if (!show)
       language = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Language"];
    else 
       return key;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"];

    if ( !path )

        return NSLocalizedString(key, nil);

    return [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] localizedStringForKey:(key) value: @"" table:nil];
}
```

So where you need, you can show only key (your base value)..